# Fill two even sized columns with even sized buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a menu. This menu should contain buttons arranged in two columns.
The width of each button should be 50% of the available screen width.

I already managed to get each button the same size. But I want that each button is 50% of the screen width no matter how many characters the buttons contain.
Furthermor I need to work with relative sizes beacuase I have to support different screen resolutions.

Here is wat I got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/PJ9cJ/

```
<div class="actions" id="actions">
        <div id="steuerung">
            <table class="actions_table" border="0" >
                <tr >
                    <td>
                            <a href="javascript:displaySomething();" class="action_button" >Button 1</a>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                            <a href="javascript:displaySomething();" class="action_button" >Button 2</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td >
                            <a href="javascript:displaySomething();" class="action_button"  >Button 3</a>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                            <a href="javascript:displaySomething();" class="action_button" >Button 4</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in here you can see my problem:
[image]
I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: have your tried a display block for your links and a width of 50%?

Comment: Which buttons are we talking about? The ones labeled button1 - 4? Also, can you post some of your CSS so we can see how you're styling so far. Sounds like What Sven Bieder said would be the first thing I'd code, but you haven't mentioned any methods you've tried so far.

Comment: We are (according to my html) dalking about button 1-4.  
The corresponding CSS is in the jsfiddle link.
I played around with `display:block` on both the `<td>` and the `<tr>` but that didn't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I made the table 100% the width of the element it is in, and floated its parent div (actions) left and made it 100%. Then I did a few adjustments to the margin of the action_button class.

```
.actions_table{
    width:100%;
    border-spacing:0;
}
#actions{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.action_button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed',       endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:50%;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    padding:1em 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PJ9cJ/11/

Comment: I literally love you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I din't understand what the actual problem you are suffering from? But I wanted you to say that if you are aligning `<td>` element to same size with column. The best is to use for `<td>` element, define `display: inline-block;` after this you could adjust the `display: block;` to other elements. Or if this doesn't work, please show me a pic what exactly you want (only your column pic).